# ShareLaTeX compilation flags

Tags: sharelatex

Is it possible and if so how can you pass flags to the ShareLaTeX compiler which one would have passed as parameters to the LaTeX compiler?

I am using the minted package and need to pass the `-shell-escape` flag.

Comment: You are _very_ unlikely to be allowed shell escape on a server-based installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ShareLaTeX announced in their newsletter from January 28th 2014, that their compiler now [supports](http://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_Highlighting_with_minted) the minted package

Comment: ONLY if you place it in the root folder of your project - if you place it in a subdirectory it breaks.

Comment: Wow, that really got me confused. Thanks. They should be more clear with that.

Comment: Note that it also supports converting images from pdf format to png images

Answer (score 3):

Without an 'official line' from the ShareLaTeX people, the answer we can give is *almost certainly* 'no'. The `-shell-escape` system is turned off as standard for a reason: there are security issues. On a server, these become even more important than on a stand-alone machine. Even if you were allowed `-shell-escape`, without Pygmentize installed `minted` still won't work.

It would be possible for ShareLaTeX to install Pygmentize and add it to the 'trusted' list of programs that LaTeX can run without `-shell-escape`, but `minted` actually checks for `-shell-escape` so this wouldn't work. You are therefore out of luck, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Alltough a few weeks old now, people might still be interested in a solution. 
If you are running your own docker, you get this done quite simple by activating the

`-shell-escape`

flag and installing the software and packages you need (in your case `minted`). But keep in mind, this is a severe security issue as users can basically run every bash command out of LaTeX now!
Edit `/var/www/pdflatex` and add the flag, thats all you need to do. 
You can also move

`pdflatex` (in <kbd>/usr/bin/</kbd> or something like this) to `pdflatex_orig`

and replace `pdflatex` through a script calling `pdflatex_orig` with addtionally added flags. 
Not much work to be done to edit this, but of course you need your own ShareLaTeX docker to do so.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).